# Custom Authentication - Spring boot 403 forbidden error

Tags: mongodb, authentication, spring-boot, jwt, http-status-code-403

I was trying it implement custom authentication,  Authentication works fine, but have problems with Authorization.  I am using JWT tokens, Any API I try to access it throwing me a 403 forbidden error. I am not sure what is wrong. I have the full source code in github. https://github.com/vivdso/SpringAuthentication, Spring boot magic is not working on this. Any pointers are apperciated. 
Using MongoDb as my repository to store user accounts and roles.
InMemory Authentication is working fine, but Custom Authentication always returs 403, Below is my I extended  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
//        authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
//        authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
```

authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(getCustomAuthenticationProvider());
        }

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/customer").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/order").hasAuthority("USER").and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

@Bean
    protected CustomAuthenticationProvider getCustomAuthenticationProvider(){
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
    }
```

I don't have any custom implementation for authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, I have updated Github repository. The spring boot security was working fine, the issue was the roles assigned to the user collection was  a Json  string object (e.g. {"role":"ROLE_ADMIN"}) instead of sting object "ROLE_ADMIN".

Thanks